# How to update value got from a query on clicking a button in another component using react, typescript and graphql?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

i want to update the value i got from the graphql query when a button is clicked from another component.

What i am trying to do?
I have a ButtonComponent that has a "Add" button and label "count" which gets a value from graphql query named getCount.

There is CountViewComponent that has label "showAvailableCount" which gets value from same graphql query named getCount.

This getCount query returns availablebookscount, availablepenscount, totalbookscount, totalpenscount and is like below,

```
export const GET_COUNT = gql`
    query GetCount {
        getCount {
            totalpenscount
            totalbookscount
            availablepenscount
            avaialbalebookscount
        }
    }
`;
```

The ButtonComponent is like below,

```
function ButtonComponent () {
    const { count } = useGetCount();
    const availablepenscount = count.availablepenscount;
    const onAdd = async () => {
        await createItem({ email: email, Id: id }); //this is the mutation
    };
    render = () => {
        return (
            <button onClick={onAdd}>Add</button>
            <span>Count</span>
            <span>{availablepenscount}</span>
        )
    }
}
```

In this component on clicking add button i call createItem mutation. within createItem mutation i update the cache for availablepenscount by decreasing the value by 1 and hence updating the Count variable.

the createItem mutation looks like below,

```
const createItem = (variables: CreateInput) => {
    return mutation({
        variables,
        update: (cache, {data}) => {
            if (!data) return;

        const ListCache: any = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS });
        ListCache.listItems.push(data.createItem);
        cache.writeQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS, data: ListCache });
        const cacheData: any = cache.readQuery({query: GET_COUNT});
            cacheData.getCount.availablepenscount--;//updating 
            //availablepencount from cache
            cacheData.getCount.availablebookscount--;
            cache.writeQuery({
                query: GET_COUNT,
                data: cacheData,
            });
        },
    });
    return { createItem, result };
}
```

and the result looks like below,

```
createItem:
    email: "some_email.com"
    id: "1"
```

the **countViewComponent** looks like below,

```
function countViewComponent () {
    const { count } = useGetCount();
    const availablepenscount = count.availablepenscount;
    render = () => {
        return (
            <span>ShowAvailable</span>
            <span>{availablepenscount}</span>
        )
    }
}
```

How can i update this showAvailableCount value when Add button is clicked. the availablepenscount variable value in ButtonComponent updates as expected with the cache. but doesnt work the same within CountViewComponent.

Could someone help me fix this. I am new to using typescript and graphql. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here there is two things. CountViewComponent that shows the data from the query GET_COUNT and the ButtonComponent that shows the same data as in CountViewComponnet from the query GET_COUNT.

there is one input field. when user enters email and clicks add button from ButtonComponent, createItem mutation is called to add this email to list of available items.

When user adds email this availablepencount value should decreaase by 1.

Rather than querying graphql server again for this data...i update the cache during create item mutation as seen from code above...

until here it works fine...

Now the question is, this countViewComponent should have the same value as the ButtonComponent after  add button clicked....

**updating cache in Buttoncomponent isnot rendering the same value in countViewComponent......**

How can i do it. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

**Edit2:**
Based on answer provided tried below, and it updates the count value in countViewComponent on clicking add button for second time

```
update: (cache, { data }) => {
   const cacheData: any = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_COUNT });
   cacheData.getCount.totalpenscount = 
       cacheData.getCount.totalpenscount + 0;
   cacheData.getCount.totalbookscount = 
       cacheData.getCount.totalbookscount + 0;
   cacheData.getCount.availablepenscount = 
       cacheData.getCount.availablepenscount + 1;
   cacheData.getCount.availablebookscount = 
       cacheData.getCount.availablebookscount + 0;
   cacheData.__typename = 'Count';
   cache.writeQuery({
       query: GET_COUNT,
       data: cacheData,
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks could you please explain it in more detail.

Comment: sorry..i am new to using graphql and typescript and i am not clearly getting the point.so should i create a state in the CountViewComponent? could you show me the snippet pointing to what to be done if not full. just want to get the jist. thanks.

Comment: this updated value is already in database...i should query it to get new values...i updated cache in create mutation since that was easy to do....but actually we have the updated values in db ready... or something that i was suggested to do.

Comment: sorry ... you should use mutation result (`data`) to mutate cache, not readed data - see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates (`{ data: { addTodo } }`) - `addTodo` is written to cache

Comment: your query and mutation result are the same type? you can try to just `cache.writeQuery({ query: GET_COUNT, data });`  (where data means/shortcut `data:data`)

Comment: my query and mutation result are different...this is a query and no mutation seperate for this. we cannot edit these values and store it to db...but we get all updated values direct from db...

Comment: .... show query and mutation definitions, usage, sample response data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving alone not using remote counters data...

**Cache should be updated using immutable methods - by creating new objects, not by mutations of existing ones.** This way apollo can detect/react on change (and force updates of observed queries).

```
    const ListCache: any = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS });
    ListCache.listItems.push(data.createItem);
    cache.writeQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS, data: ListCache });
```

should be

```
    // concat returns a new array
    const newList: any = cache.readQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS }).concat (data.createItem); 
    cache.writeQuery({ query: LIST_ITEMS, data: newList });
```

and

```
    const cacheData: any = cache.readQuery({query: GET_COUNT});
        cacheData.getCount.availablepenscount--;//updating 
        //availablepencount from cache
        cacheData.getCount.availablebookscount--;
        cache.writeQuery({
            query: GET_COUNT,
            data: cacheData,
        });
```

should be (something like):

```
    const cacheData: any = cache.readQuery({query: GET_COUNT});
    const newCounter: any = { ...cacheData.getCount }; // new object
    newCounter.availablepenscount--;//updating properties
    newCounter.availablebookscount--;
    cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_COUNT,
        data: {
          __typename: 'Count',
          getCount: newCounter
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks.so will this update the value within countViewComponent as well on add button click?

Comment: should update any component where both queries were used

Comment: somehow it just doesnt work for me ..it is not updating for the ButtonComponent too now.

Comment: actually no i changed it to code like in my question(under edit2 section) based on your answer and it updates on second click on add button. for example if count value is 4 clicking add btn will set count value in Buttoncomponent to 3 and countViewComponent remains 4. clicking on add btn again sets value to 3 in both ButtonComponent and countViewComponent. I am not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: @someuser2491 try updated 'update' - the key is a new object for internal part - `console.log(data)` in `update` ... wait a second for updates

Comment: also what i have found out is instead of updating the cache for the getcount query refetch queries works perfect updating both the ButtonComponent and countViewComponent instantly at the same time. but i don want to use refetchqueries and want to use updatecache :/

Comment: your answer works thanks a lot. i had some mistakes which made it not work. but  how does it make it different copying the cacheData to a newObject?

Comment: usually (many cases, naturally required in redux for the same reason) compared is object reference - the same object (the same ref) mutation is not detected as change ... immutable.js enforces/helps with deeper updates